# Wordpress rest-api authentication from react app for non-logged in user

Tags: reactjs, authentication, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a series of react apps which are injected to wordpress websites (survey like apps to gather **guest/non-logged in** users data).

The final step requires creating new post in wordpress with all the gathered data - I'm trying to use rest-api to accomplish this.

To use wordpress rest-api I at least need to authenticate with ANY user so I started with mentioned in documentation authentication methods like "application passwords" or JWT token generation (plugin) and trying to auth wordpress admin user created for this purpose only.

It turned out both methods requires using credentials on frontend react app to POST data to the wordpress rest-api. The problem is:

- I'm trying to hide authentication so its happening without user registration or any other action being taken on their part to save the form
- when using "application password" I need to put credentials on react app to make a POST request -  *but its exposing credentials*
- when using JWT Token approach - I can get token only if I send username and password from react app - but its then *again exposing login details*

**Is there a way I could:**

- exchange credentials between wordpress and react app in a form of encrypted data? (eg through cookies)
- or authenticate react app in other way?
- or create wordpress post from react app in a different way?

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested how this can be done:

1. No auth, rest-api solution - using js ajax call to invoke php script and handle rest api call internally on server side, then getting response back to JS
   pros:

- no auth step, we still utilize wordpress rest-api but internally on the server
- just by adding or removing add_action we can specify if the code can be triggered by logged in or non logged in users
  *the below example is not using reactjs but jQuery.ajax but this can be easily replaced on frontend by anything react related (axios or similar)

functions.php / plugin php file:

```
function pp_reactapp_ajax( ){
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'script-checker', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script-checker.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pp_reactpp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/pp_reactpp.js', ['jquery'] );
    wp_localize_script( 'pp_reactpp', 'pp_reactapp', array(
                    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_reactapp_ajax' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_reactapp_ajax' );
```

the code above is to get js file with ajax call and output ajaxurl to be used in that file (see below)

```
function pp_check_reactapp_ajax() {

    $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'POST', '/wp/v2/posts' );
    $request->set_header( 'content-type', 'application/json' );
    $request->set_body( '{
            "title": "'. $_POST['title'] .'"
        }');

    $response = rest_do_request( $request );

    $server = rest_get_server();
    $data = $server->response_to_data( $response, false );

    if($data['id']){
        echo '{"success": '. json_encode($data) .'}';
    } else {
        echo '{"error": "'. $data['message'] .'"}';
    }

    wp_die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pp_check_reactapp_ajax', 'pp_check_reactapp_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pp_check_reactapp_ajax', 'pp_check_reactapp_ajax' );
```

this is php function which is executed by ajax call
ajax call on js file data.action is connecting it with php function name

example js ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: pp_reactapp.ajaxurl,
  data: {
      action: 'pp_check_reactapp_ajax',
      title: 'new post works with ajax ALL WORKS 2',
  },
  beforeSend: function ( ) {
      jQuery( 'body' ).html( pp_reactapp.loading_message );
  },
  success: function ( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    
  },
  error: function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log( errorThrown );
  }
});
```

2. auth solution

An idea: this is still not ideal but with similar to the above approach we can generate token by php call to rest-api (get token) for a user credentials responsible for authenticating react app, then output it with localize_script to frontend where reactapp can read it and attach to headers for request.

To move forward with securing the token - Instead of outputing with localize_script I would request token generation and sending to frontend just before data needs to be transmitted to rest-api (using ajax call to execute php from above example) and send it back with very short lifetime (eg 20s).
This way even if token is exposed without "proper authorization" - it still can be used but only for very limited time.